# How can I access the current URI in a view during testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have a shared view component that changes state based on the current URI. I'm currently accessing that information via `request.env['PATH_INFO']`, as this seems to be the convention as far as I can tell. However, when running unit tests, this always seems to be `nil`. This is an issue, because it causes any view with this component to explode.

Setting `@request.env['PATH_INFO']` in the body of the test doesn't work, and I'm glad it doesn't because that would be hideous.

---

**How can I access the current URI within a view or controller during testing?**

---

<sub>I'm using vanilla Rails unit testing, so answers that don't require me to change my testing framework would be much appreciated.</sub>

Comment: Can't you mock the `request` object for your Unit tests? Something like `helper.request.stub(:path).and_return( 'your path' )`...

Comment: @AndreasRayoKniep Not without switching to `rspec`, and anyway setting the appropriate value by hand before every test is pretty grody. What about cases where a redirect needs to be followed? I'd have to change the stub mid-request.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `request.fullpath` still holds the right info in a testing environment. Using that instead of the `env` hash solved it!